# Jquery - Auto click issue while load form

Tags: jquery

I have button in the form, when loading the page that button need to click automatically , so i implemented trigger function in loading the page.**but its keep on loading page** ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#find").trigger('click');
}

<s:form action="productlist" id="searchForm" theme="simple" method="Post" onSubmit="FormSubmitHandler()">       
 <s:submit action="product" method="list" value="Find" />
</s:form>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Provide the HTML please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the cause of the issue.  **You are not closing the function properly.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#find').trigger('click');
});
```

check **console(press F12)** to see error messages.